SQL query to update serial number of consecutive values
I am looking for support to find the sequence number based on the employee, effective date and the order which the data received in the file.
Same employee, effective date combination can come any row. Same serial number needs to allocate for the consecutive rows. And the serial number should be continuous
create table hrcmn_emp_full_table
(
    employee_code           varchar(Max),
    movement_code           varchar(Max),
    effective_date          varchar(10),
    filename                varchar(Max),
    file_sequence           int,
    process_sequence        int,
    effective_date_sequence int,
    final_process_sequence  int,
    MyGroup int
)

insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('1001','NEWHR','2020-02-01','XXX.txt',1)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('1001','NEWHR','2020-01-01','XXX.txt',2)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('1001','NEWHR','2020-01-01','XXX.txt',3)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('1001','NEWHR','2020-02-01','XXX.txt',4)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('1001','NEWHR','2020-01-01','XXX.txt',5)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('2001','NEWHR','2020-02-01','YYY.txt',1)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('2001','NEWHR','2020-01-01','YYY.txt',2)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('2001','NEWHR','2020-01-01','YYY.txt',3)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('2001','NEWHR','2020-02-01','YYY.txt',4)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('2002','NEWHR','2020-03-01','YYY.txt',5)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('2001','NEWHR','2020-01-01','YYY.txt',6)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('3001','NEWHR','2020-01-01','ZZZ.txt',1)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('3001','NEWHR','2020-02-01','ZZZ.txt',2)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('3002','NEWHR','2020-10-01','ZZZ.txt',3)
insert into hrcmn_emp_full_table(employee_code,movement_code,effective_date,filename,file_sequence) values ('3001','NEWHR','2020-02-01','ZZZ.txt',4)


;with processnum as (select filename,[file_sequence],[employee_code],[effective_date],
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition BY filename,[employee_code] ORDER BY [file_sequence],[effective_date]) as processnum      
     from hrcmn_emp_full_table with (nolock))  
      
update tmp  
set process_sequence = num.processnum
from hrcmn_emp_full_table tmp, processnum num
where tmp.filename = num.filename
  and tmp.[file_sequence] = num.[file_sequence]
  and tmp.[employee_code] = num.[employee_code]
  and tmp.[effective_date] = num.[effective_date]
  and tmp.process_sequence is null

;with processnum as (select filename,employee_code,file_sequence,a.[movement_code],[effective_date],
     dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY [effective_date],a.movement_code) as rank_function_mov
     from hrcmn_emp_full_table a with (nolock)
)
update tmp  
set effective_date_sequence = num.rank_function_mov
from hrcmn_emp_full_table tmp, processnum num
where tmp.filename      = num.filename
  and tmp.[movement_code] = num.[movement_code] 
  and tmp.[effective_date] = num.[effective_date]
  and tmp.employee_code = num.employee_code
  and tmp.file_sequence = num.file_sequence
  and tmp.effective_date_sequence is null

  
DECLARE @MyGroup INT
    SET @MyGroup = 0
DECLARE @LastProcess_Sequence DECIMAL(6,2)
    SET @LastProcess_Sequence = -1
    
    --updating consecutive group
    UPDATE a
    SET @MyGroup = MyGroup = CASE
                               WHEN a.Process_Sequence = @LastProcess_Sequence + 1
                               THEN @MyGroup
                               ELSE @MyGroup+1
                             END,
        @LastProcess_Sequence = a.Process_Sequence
   FROM hrcmn_emp_full_table a,
        ( SELECT DISTINCT t1.filename,t1.file_sequence,
        t1.Effective_date_sequence,t1.Process_Sequence
        FROM hrcmn_emp_full_table t1,
        hrcmn_emp_full_table t2
        WHERE (t1.Process_Sequence+1 = t2.Process_Sequence)
        AND t1.Effective_date_sequence   = t2.Effective_date_sequence
        AND t1.filename = t2.filename
        UNION 
        SELECT DISTINCT t1.filename,t1.file_sequence,
        t1.Effective_date_sequence,t1.Process_Sequence
        FROM hrcmn_emp_full_table t1,
        hrcmn_emp_full_table t2
        WHERE (t1.Process_Sequence-1 = t2.Process_Sequence)
        AND t1.Effective_date_sequence   = t2.Effective_date_sequence
        AND t1.filename = t2.filename) w
  where a.file_sequence = w.file_sequence
   and a.Effective_date_sequence = w.Effective_date_sequence
   and a.Process_Sequence = w.Process_Sequence
   AND a.filename = w.filename


 update a
 set final_process_sequence = T.final
 from hrcmn_emp_full_table a , 
             (select min(process_sequence) 'final',effective_date_sequence,filename
             from hrcmn_emp_full_table
             where MyGroup is null
             group by effective_date_sequence,filename) T
 where a.effective_date_sequence = T.effective_date_sequence
 and a.filename = T.filename
 and a.MyGroup is null


 update a
 set    final_process_sequence = T.final
 from   hrcmn_emp_full_table a , 
     (select min(process_sequence) 'final',effective_date_sequence,MyGroup,filename
     from   hrcmn_emp_full_table with (nolock)
      where MyGroup is not null
     group by effective_date_sequence,MyGroup,filename) T
 where a.effective_date_sequence = T.effective_date_sequence
 and a.MyGroup is not null
 and a.MyGroup = T.MyGroup
 and a.filename = T.filename

I am getting the below output,

However, expecting the below output.

Could anyone support in this?

To get the "final process sequence" you only need this:
with dataX as (
    select *,
        lag(effective_date) over (
            partition by filename
            order by file_sequence) as last_effective_date
    from hrcmn_emp_full_table
)
select employee_code, effective_date, filename, file_sequence,
    -- batch by changes in date when running in file sequence order
    sum(case when effective_date = last_effective_date then 0 else 1 end) over (
        partition by filename
        order by file_sequence) as final_process_sequence
from dataX
order by file_sequence;

Otherwise, to compute and update all the columns:
with dataX as (
    select *,
        row_number() over (
            partition by filename, employee_code
            order by file_sequence) as process_sequence_new,
        dense_rank() over (
            order by effective_date, movement_code) as effective_date_sequence_new,
        lag(effective_date) over (
            partition by filename
            order by file_sequence) as last_effective_date
    from hrcmn_emp_full_table
), dataY as (
    select *,
        sum(case when effective_date = last_effective_date then 0 else 1 end) over (
            partition by filename
            order by file_sequence) as final_process_sequence_new
    from dataX
)
update dataY
set process_sequence = process_sequence_new,
    effective_date_sequence = effective_date_sequence_new,
    final_process_sequence = final_process_sequence_new;

I've left out the MyGroup calculation since I'm fairly confident that was only an intermediate step. While I suspect the others are as well, I'm less confident about that. Absolutely remove what you no longer need.
Update: Actually, I looked closer at a way to salvage the attempt at using MyGroup to get to the end result, mostly for educational purposes. I couldn't think of a simple tweak and highly recommend using analytic functions as with my solution above.
https://dbfiddle.uk/P8CrfNfT

Thanks for your reply shawnt.  your query finds all the sequence for the consecutive rows. For the single row employee cases to be find 1 as a final sequence. but it gives different result.
I expect the below result.
for the employee's 2002, 3002 the final sequence should be 1.

Also for the employee "3001" last row in my record set the final sequence which i expect is 3 not 2. It should not group that row with previous rows

@Girija You changed the data completely. Good luck with that but I'm not wasting more of my time. Try actually describing what you want in words so somebody else might take a crack at it.

your query is useful. thanks
